# multiplayer Java game ,splitting issue

Tags: java, networking, client-server

I have a multiplayer java game(four client and a server) which all classes were in a single file i have decided to rewrite the main class and keep the code in multiple shorter classes.Everything seems to be fine (no syntax error or run time error), from Server side it seems to be fine but not from the client side
I decided to use Print statement to get to the  bug , it seems that the client is not able to work  over below code:

```
public class ServerManager implements Runnable {


public static BufferedReader in;

public static PrintWriter out;


private Socket socket;

@Override
public void run() {
    try
    {
        socket = Connection.connectToServer(GameStatus.serverIP, GameStatus.serverPort);
        if(socket != null) {
            return;
        } else {

        }

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

The working version of application for this particular area , is as below

```
BufferedReader in;
PrintWriter out;
public static void main(String[] args) {
....
....
....
private class startClient implements Runnable {
        private Socket socket;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try
            {
                try {
                    socket = new Socket(serverIP, serverPort);
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                    return;
                }
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

Does my code have any issues?

Answer (score 0):

well , I had put the try in the beginning of socket connection , and catch the exception at the end of the class , just gave it a try and kept the catch right after the the socket connection and it worked.

```
     try
    {
        try{
        socket = Connection.connectToServer(GameStatus.serverIP, GameStatus.serverPort);
        //if(socket != null) {
            //return;
        //} else {

    //  }
        } catch (Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can not connect to server!");
            if(ex.toString().trim().equals("java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server is down!\nThe game will now exit...");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            //else
        }
    //}

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
```